How to view all the intermediate messages in Cognify optimized workflow
Cognify(https://github.com/GenseeAI/cognify/tree/main) is a tool that automatically enhances generation quality and reduces costs for gen-AI workflows.
When I finished the optimization process, how can I view the final workflow, especially to view all the intermediate messages from the input to the output
